# how to serve Unique Items from Database via rails upon every request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am running a "Master" server, along with 4 "slaves".

The master is an http running a rails app server, and slaves are ec2 instances running a script.

The slaves send a http request to the master, to which the master responds with a json query of an item in the database. **Before the request is served, the master is supposed to set the field named -sent- to "TRUE"** so that the item is not served again.

Steps:

- Receive Request.
- Look up item from database.
- Set field **sent** to true.
- Send JSON back of the database item.

**Problem**

I see in the shell output of the scripts, that although the data is served, sometimes the same thing is served to two slaves at the same time.

---

```
class Places < ActiveRecord::Base

def sentout
   self.update_attributes(:sent => "True")
end

def self.worker
   @a = Places.select("id,address,city").where("sent is null").first
   @a.sentout
   return @a.to_json
end

end
```

In the view, this is what happens:

```
  def index
     @a = Places.worker
     render :json => @a
  end
```

According to this, no matter how many slaves I have asking for data to process, it should be churning out UNIQUE data (sent field is ""), but I am seeing same items in outputs of 2 scripts which means that sometimes the slave machines end up processing same thing twice.

Is this the right way to approach this problem? I am new to this, and am trying the most logical approach.

Any help would be appreciated which I try to solve this on my own.

Answer (score 0):

The following will return true, but will not update the status attribute.

```
Place.update_attributes(:sent => 'True')
```

If you want to update the status attribute, you should assign it separately.

```
Place.sent = 'True'
save
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested. I am still seeing duplicates. 

Does the rest of the code look like it should do what I am expecting it to?